# Vim script unexpected behavior

Tags: vim

I have the following piece of code in my Vim function:

```
:$
set nomodified
:wincmd k
```

It must move the cursor to the end of the current buffer, make it unmodifiable, then move the cursor to another split. The problem is that it does not move the cursor to the end of the current buffer.

When I comment the last line, it moves the cursor. How to fix such behavior?

Comment: Do you have any autocmds that may interfere? Try with `:set eventignore=all`.

Comment: `:set nomodified` doesn't make the buffer "unmodifiable", it makes it "not modified". Use `:set nomodifiable` if you want to make it "not modifiable". Anyway, putting these lines verbatim in a function works as expected, here: the cursor jumps to the last line of the current buffer and the focus goes to the window above.

Comment: @romainl you should put that as an answer, so the poster can accept it.

Comment: No. It doesn't answer his question nor fix his problem. I just say that I can't reproduce the "bug".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:call cursor('$', 0)
:set nomodifiable
:wincmd k
```